# Kotlin flow - Is flow created once for each collector?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I know `Flow` is [cold](https://elizarov.medium.com/cold-flows-hot-channels-d74769805f9), and `ShaerdFlow` is [hot](https://www.raywenderlich.com/22030171-reactive-streams-on-kotlin-sharedflow-and-stateflow).

To test cold stream in Kotlin flow, I created below code. My plan is, create a flow that will emit String value and add two collectors on it. I expect that the only one collector will get emitted value, because it is a cold stream.

But the result was different, I found that two values are emitted!

**Test code:**

```
    val stringFlow: Flow<String> = flow<String> {
        for (i in 0..10) {
            Timber.d("Integer $i emitted ${currentCoroutineContext()}")
            emit("Integer $i")
            delay(500)
        }
    }
    // If I uncomment below line, only one flow will be emitted
    //.shareIn(coroutineScope, SharingStarted.Lazily) 


    val job1 = coroutineScope.launch {
        stringFlow.collect {
            Timber.d("job1 collect 1 $it")
        }
    }
    val job2 = coroutineScope.launch {
        stringFlow.collect {
            Timber.d("job2 collect 2 $it")
        }
    }
```

**Result:**

```
stringFlow: Integer 0 produced [StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@c2f624, Dispatchers.IO]
stringFlow: Integer 0 produced [StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@dd9f58d, Dispatchers.IO]
job1: job1 collect 1 Integer 0
job2: job2 collect 2 Integer 0
```

How can I explain this situation? Can I say "flow will be created once for each collector?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it starts emitting a new flow/stream of items whenever we start collecting from it. This is described in the [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow.html):

> The flow being cold means that the block is called every time a terminal operator is applied to the resulting flow.

It is the same for other cold flows as well. For example, flow created with `flowOf()` emits the same items whenever collected. Flow created with `callbackFlow()` attaches a callback whenever we collect. And so on.

> I expect that the only one collector will get emitted value

If you meant to distribute work between multiple consumers, then I believe flows are not a good fit for this. They are more about observing for events or some data, but not for distributing of items between multiple producers and consumers. Use [channels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html) instead.